# Best astrophysics textbook if I hold a PhD in nuclear engineering

Tags: astrophysics, resource-recommendations, education

I am looking for the best astrophysics book or combination of books given my background.

I have a PhD in nuclear engineering and I am still doing research in the nuclear field. I develop mathematical models for radiation transport, hydrodynamics, shock physics and MHD, as well as to study the interaction among these physics.

Although these physics play a role in astrophysics, I work with them for nuclear engineering applications. As such, I have a gap to fill as far as astrophysical phenomena are concerned. I am looking for one or more textbooks that can give me a broad overview of the main astrophysical phenomena without being to oversimplifying (details on maths derivation would be a plus). After that, I’d like to go deeper into stellar life cycle and planet formation. I would not dislike if I will be able, in the future, to apply my expertise to publish something in this field.

Comment: You might fin this MIT open courses series helpful https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-901-astrophysics-i-spring-2006/

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44882/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic that discussion is for grad/undergrad books. This is why I specified my background...