# Introductory books on astrophysics

Tags: astrophysics, resource-recommendations, astronomy, education

I'm looking to get deeper into astrophysics and physics in general. I already know physics from the internet (YouTube physics channels, etc.). I don't have a lot of mathematical skills. I know some algebra, but nothing above that. However, I'll learn more advanced mathematics (algebra, trigonometry, and potentially calculus).

I know there are many, many popular science books about physics and astrophysics. But, most of them do not go into a lot of detail, are usually only a few hundred pages long, and rarely have mathematics. I found a book *Welcome to the Universe* by Tyson et al., that goes into a bit more depth and contains some mathematics; it's about 480 pages long.

I know of several undergraduate/graduate-level textbooks on physics and astrophysics, but those are too advanced for me, especially where mathematics is concerned. Do you have recommendations for (text)books similar to *Welcome to the Universe* that go into more depth and have mathematics about those topics but not advanced mathematics such as calculus?

Comment: Check out textbooks for first-year Introduction to Astronomy university courses, especially those targeted to non-science majors. Simply do an internet search for what universities use in their courses.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44882/2451 and links therein.